# Generate KML lineString coordinates with curvature of the earth at higher altitude

Tags: kml, google-earth

I need to create a lineString between two points at a higher altitude that has the curvature of the earth. Think along the lines of something similar to airline flight paths for a visual idea.

Between any two beginning and end points there would be a straight line when looking from above, but from the side it would match the curvature of the earth.

Let's say the line has to appear at an altitude of 260,000 above the earth. If I just specify the beginning and end point, over long distances the line goes through the earth.

(to reduce clutter, I'm going to leave out the rest of the KML code, and just paste the LineString code)

**Example 1:**

```
<Placemark>
  <name>LineString Test</name>
      <visibility>1</visibility>
  <description>Test</description>
  <styleUrl>#RedLine</styleUrl>
  <LineString>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>

          -86.1296598,38.8760649,260000

          -97.7430608,30.267153,260000
</coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

If I do this, the line has a nice curve to it that matches the curvature of the earth.

Example 2

```
    <Placemark>
  <name>LineString Test</name>
      <visibility>1</visibility>
  <description>Test</description>
  <styleUrl>#RedLine</styleUrl>
  <LineString>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>

          -86.1296598,38.8760649,260000
          -87.1854235,38.0934366,260000
          -88.2411872,37.3108083,260000
          -89.2969509,36.52818,260000
          -90.3527146,35.7455517,260000
          -91.4084783,34.9629234,260000
          -92.464242,34.1802951,260000
          -93.5200057,33.3976668,260000
          -94.5757694,32.6150385,260000
          -95.6315331,31.8324102,260000
          -96.6872968,31.0497819,260000
          -97.7430608,30.267153,260000
</coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

Example two is the desired result, however is there an easier way to accomplish this, or will I need some sort of algorithm to calculate the points in between the beginning and end point along the route to achieve the curvature of the earth?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020997/google-earth-api-drawing-lines-that-curve

Comment: That sets the line on the ground. I need curved linestrings drawn at a altitudes higher than 0.

Comment: @livi1717: Did you ever find out if Google kml has a way to show the line correct?

Comment: @Werner: No I was never able to find a solution for this problem. Are you looking for the same solution?

Comment: @livi1717: Yes, and this weekend I implemented some routines from Mike Gavaghans Geodetic Calculator (C#) which enables me to calculate "helper" points along the path. But as you say, there should be a better way :)

Comment: Can I ask you to provide a link to where you found the solution?